# Paypal alternatives for personal site donations "adult friendly"

Tags: payments, paypal, payment-gateway, adult-content

Paypal has a policy against having using them if your site has *any* adult content. I'm wondering if there are any services that work similar to paypal, but that don't mind some adult content, or being somehow connected to it

little history is that a blogger I read got kicked off of paypal. tried to open a new site on a non sex related topic for donations due to a child custody battle, and paypal shut that off because the account is "related" to the previous account. I personally don't agree with this. So I'm curious what options might exist for something that's not so profitable and doesn't need a "full payment gateway"

Comment: Yea, I'm not a big fan of PayPal, but unfortunately they are the defacto non-CC online payment provider. The barrier to entry is too great for any real alternatives to arise since PayPal already has a large user base and brand recognition, and I doubt you'll be able to get most people to sign up for a Google Checkout account just to give you a donation. Which is too bad...

Answer (score 1):

[CCBill](http://www.ccbill.com/)

Comment: So CCBill doesn't have a monthly fee for merchants? What is their rate per transaction?